# スマホからサイトを確認するとフォントが変更されていない

Tags: html, css, wordpress

wordpressのaffinger5を使ってwebページを作成しました。
[image: affinger管理 > デザイン の設定は以下のようにしております。]

pcから開発者モードでスマホ用の画面で確認するとフォントは設定した通りに表示されております。
しかし、実際のスマホで確認すると機種を問わず、デフォルトのフォントになってしまいます。

なにかプラグインが影響していたりするのでしょうか？
2枚目がインストールしたプラグイン一覧です。
どうか、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
[image: プラグイン一覧]

Comment: マルチポスト ⇒ https://qiita.com/shinjiukai/questions/d0c13ca671944250bbad

Comment: Wordpressの画面の意味が正確には理解できませんが、スクリーンショットを見るとフォント名として游明朝を指定しているということでしょうか。
そうだとすると、游明朝がインストールされていない環境では反映されません。
Androidなどのスマートフォンは通常、游明朝がインストールされていないと思います。
それともプラグイン画面に少し写っていますが Google Fonts を使おうとなさっているのでしょうか。
その場合は、Google Fonts を指定する設定が必要なはずですが、それはスクリーンショット内になさそうです。
（いずれにしろ、スクリーンショットだけでなく本文でも説明が有ると回答が得られやすいです。）

Comment: [teratail でも同様の投稿をしている](https://teratail.com/questions/jl6656upas36jf) ようで、そちらでは既に回答もついていますが、mjy さんの指摘と同じように「クライアント環境に存在しないフォントであるなら (指定したフォントでは) 表示されない」と書かれています。

Answer (score 0):

Google Fonts を指定する設定を確認してみます！
それでだめならwebフォントを使ってみます！ありがとうございます。